# Must in indirect speech

Tags: reported-speech

I have a problem with "must" in indirect speech.

1. ( I must leave now )

- He said that he must now ( Answer in the book )

Can anyone explain why this answer ( adding must without a verb ?)  or Is there a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Oftentimes "must" in direct speech will be changed to "had to" in indirect speech, but you do not necessarily have to. For your example, changing "must" in indirect speech would look something like this:

> He said that he had to leave now.

Pertaning to your question, you can add must without a verb directly after it, as long as a verb follows after whatever you are adding.

> He said that he must now leave.

In this case, "leave" is still the verb that is used after must. If the answer is just `he must now`, the book probably has a mistake.

Comment: I'd say rather that "must" can be replaced by "have to" in *any* kind of speech, and usually is except in formal speech. "I must leave now" is quite formal; "I have to leave now" is perfectly ordinary.

Answer (score 1):

"He said that he must now" is not necessarily *wrong*, but I think it is likely to be misunderstood. That makes it a bad answer.

"Must" needs to go with a verb, but by [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)), that verb can be implied rather than being stated. Here's an example of it being used well:

> "I don't want to go to the party."
>
> "But you must!"

("Must **go**" is the implied verb.)

Your book's answer is a bad case of ellipsis because it won't be clear what the implied verb is. Because it's reported speech, I assume a person hearing the second statement won't have heard the first, and so they will have no clues as to what verb goes with "must"! There would need to be some other context for this to make any sense. Example:

> "Why is he leaving so soon?"
>
> "He said that he must, now."

(Final thought: if the verb is implied, then "must now" strikes me as odd. In both writing and speech, I would want a comma/pause between those two words. So I put one in my example.)